# Print a bit with VHDL (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: vhdl

I have something that I don't understand. I begin with VHDL and I don't understand how can I see the result of my circuit.
I tried to use the textio package and to print my bit result in the terminal and I tried to print this bit into a output_file.txt, but none of this tentative worked.

So my question is, how can I print a bit value? They said when I try :

```
error: port "s" cannot be read
```

There is my code :

```
Library ieee;
Use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
Use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use std.textio.all;

entity gate_AND is
    port(
    x1 : in std_logic :='1';
    x2 : in std_logic :='0';
    x3 : in std_logic :='0';
    s : out std_logic);
end entity;

architecture arc of gate_AND is

begin

    s <= x1 and x2 and x3;
process

      file OutFile : TEXT open write_mode is "output_file.txt"; 
      variable L : line;
   begin
      write (L, s);
      writeline (OutFile, L);
      wait;
   end process;
end arc;
```

Comment: I suspect that `s` being declared as an output, you can not treat it as an input, but let the VHDL experts talk...

Comment: The OP's question will work in an IEEE Std 1076-2008 compliant VHDL implementation. See 6.5.2 Interface object declarations, paragraph 12 *An interface object has one of the following modes: ... —* ***out*** *The value of the interface object is allowed to be updated and, provided it is not a signal parameter, read....*). Parameter is specific to subprograms. For tools limited to previous revisions of the VHDL standard J.H.'s answer is valid.

Comment: You can also see the result of your circuit through simulation waveform dump files and a waveform viewer. What VHDL tool are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Xhienne has the right answer: you cannot read an output port.
You should use a temporary signal or variable.

Change your code to this for instance to:

```
architecture arc of gate_AND is
begin
    process(x1, x2, x3)
        variable s_temp : std_logic;
        file OutFile : TEXT open write_mode is "output_file.txt"; 
        variable L : line;
    begin
        s_temp := x1 and x2 and x3;
        write (L, std_logic'IMAGE(s_temp));
        writeline (OutFile, L);
        s <= s_temp;
    end process;
end arc;
```

Comment: ghdl -a --std=08  gate_and.vhdl; ghdl -e --std=08 gate_and; ghdl -r gate_and; more output_file.txt (and that returns `U`). It's legal -in -2008 to read an interface object of mode out, unless it's a signal parameter (IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.2 Interface object declarations, paragraph 12 *An interface object has one of the following modes: ... —* ***out*** *The value of the interface object is allowed to be updated and, provided it is not a signal parameter, read....*). Parameter is specific to subprograms.

Comment: @user1155120 you're right. Put it in an answer and yours will probably be accepted.

Comment: Thanks for your answers everybody ! I understand that you cannot read an output port, but when I fix that, but I have an other error message :
`stackOverFullAdder.vhdl:24:15:error: cannot resolve overloading for subprogram call`
Is it because of one header?

Comment: Yes sorry. `write` doesn't support std_logic: [link](https://www.csee.umbc.edu/portal/help/VHDL/packages/textio.vhd). I've updated the code.

Comment: It work totally ! Thank you for your patience